# Why database container with mariadb fails during gitlab cicd pipeline?

Tags: docker, gitlab, cicd

I'm trying to integrate new job to existing pipeline - build `mariadb` and to execute tests and migrations on it. I have database job:

```
.db-job:
  image: mariadb:${MARIA_DB_IMAGE_VERSION}
  script:
    - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mysql --user=root --password="$DATABASE_PASSWORD" --host="$jdbc:mysql://localhost" "$DATABASE_SCHEMA"
```

I have stage for database:

```
db:install:
  stage: db
  extends: .db-job
  services:
    - name: mariadb
      alias: db
  needs: [ ]
  script:
    - cd "$BACKEND_DIR"
    - pwd
  cache:
    policy: pull-push

db:migrate:
  stage: db
  extends: .maven-job
  script:
    - cd "$BACKEND_DIR"
    - pwd
    - mvn --version
    - mvn -Dflyway.user="$DATABASE_PASSWORD" -Dflyway.schemas="DATABASE_SCHEMA" flyway:migrate
  cache:
    policy: pull-push
```

So database build passes but in logs I have error:

```
Health check error:
start service container: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container

Service container logs:
2022-11-29T11:35:15.589696287Z 2022-11-29 11:35:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.10.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2022-11-29T11:35:15.656319311Z 2022-11-29 11:35:15+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mariadbd failed while attempting to check config
```

How can I fix this problem?